# How do I delete files open in Preview?

Tags: preview

I'm having an issue with "Preview" on the Mac. When I open a document with it, I can't find the button to delete it while in preview. What I have to do now is open Launchpad to drag the document to the Trash. Does anyone know how to delete a file while in Preview?

Comment: I think there was a brief era when this worked. Then it stopped. To this day, I still try to hit various "Delete" key combos while I'm in Preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168138/122152), you can't delete the last file that's open in a Preview window:

> Preview won't allow you to cmd-delete, or "move to trash", or even drag and drop to trash, the last file it has open.

If there is more than one PDF open in a single Preview window however, you can delete them up until the last one.

Those questions might also be helpful for you:

- [How do I "Move to Trash" in Preview in OS X Lion? - Super User](https://superuser.com/q/324202/438940)
- [Preview- move to Trash - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/167376/122152)
- [Deleting a file from inside Lion’s Preview.app - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/35972/122152)